# Isn't the data insufficient in this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work

take a look at this problem:

a 1000 kg roller coaster car is towed at a constant speed up a 40 meters hill, what is the work done by the tow rope?

don't we need the slope of the hill and the static friction coefficient to solve this problem?

Comment: You should probably ignore the friction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it is assumed that rolling friction can be neglected. In this case, the answer does not depend on the slope of the hill (the kinetic energy does not change, and the change in potential energy only depends on the difference in altitude).

Comment: could you solve the problem too, if it isn't too much to ask

Comment: @Ashkan: It is against the rules of the site to give solutions to homework problems, sorry. I believe the tip I gave should be enough.

Comment: So just tell me this, Are you saying that the work of rope would be equal to the work of weight which is the change in potential energy?

Comment: @Ashkan: Not quite, they have the same magnitude, but opposite signs: the rope does the work, but work is done on the weight. But yes, the work done by the rope equals the increase in the potential energy of the weight.

Comment: @Ashkan The policy would allow it to create a question where you write down your attempts to solve it, as to be reviewed by the folks here. Not particularly for this assignment, as it is kinda solved, but for some future work.